# How can I replace multiple lines in a string?

Tags: string, language-agnostic, multiline

I want to replace multiline string as below using sed/awk/perl

```
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # supply connections
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
        connect_supply_net VSS      -ports $port(VSSE)
        connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
        connect_supply_net VDD_CPU  -ports $port(VDDPE)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Update states
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

above is the input file and I want to replace above 3 lines with as below in the output file

```
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # supply connections
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
    if { [llength $port(VSSE)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VSS -ports $port(VSSE)
    }
    if { [llength $port(VDDP)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
    }
    if { [llength $port(VDDPE)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VDD_CPU -ports $port(VDDPE)
    }

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Update states
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What would be an easier way to do this ?

I tried to use passing variable and then using the sed command but it doesn't work. I tried as below -

```
old_string="connect_supply_net VSS      -ports $port(VSSE)
connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
connect_supply_net VDD_CPU  -ports $port(VDDPE)"

new_string="if { [llength $port(VSSE)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VSS -ports $port(VSSE)
}
if { [llength $port(VDDP)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
}
if { [llength $port(VDDPE)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VDD_CPU -ports $port(VDDPE)
}"

sed -i ":a;N;$!ba;s/${old_string}/${new_string}/g" file.txt
```

However, the above didn't work. What would be an easier way to do this ?

Comment: `old_string="connect ..."` is not going to work like you think it will; because you've wrapped the strings in double quotes the `$port` components will be replaced with the contents of the `bash` variable named `port`, and if the `port` variable is undefined then `$port(VSSE)` will be saved in the variable as simply `(VSSE)`; same goes for the `new_string` assignment; in this case you want to wrap both sets of strings in single quotes so that the assignments treat the `$port` references as a literal `$` followed by the string `port`

Comment: do you need to convert *ALL* `connect_supply_net` entries or just some?  do you need to convert other entries besides the `connect_suppy_net` entries and if so then consider updating the question with a more representative set of data

Comment: Without *multiline* consideration, try simply this `sed` command: `sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)connect_supply_net .*port(\([^)]\+\))[[:space:]]*/\1if { [llength $port(\2)] > 0 } {\n\1  &\n\1}/'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with defining those variables in the shell, then you need to somehow make them available to the program that is to use them, and that program needs to read the file whole into a variable so to be able to find those multi-line patterns.  With Perl

```
$ export old_string="..."
$ export new_string="..."

$ perl -0777 -i -wnE's/$ENV{old_string}/$ENV{new_string}/g; print' filename
```

---

The above worked in my tests, but copying chunks of multiline text on the terminal is very finicky and sensitive to white-space details.  Are those tabs in there? Just how many leading spaces? Instead, this text is more easily controlled in a script.

We could enter the exact text to be matched and replaced by copy-pasting, perhaps best using [here-doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#EOF) quoting.  However, the whitespace problem remains -- is that alignment done with tabs?  Copy-pasting will lose them to spaces.  Again, am I pasting those spaces right?

Instead, form a regex pattern for that block of text, to match it with its variety of whitespace.  Here is one way.

Copy the lines and process each: break into words, in each word escape regex-special characters (there's at least `$` and parens) using [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) and then join words with `'\s+'`, then prepend `'[ \t]+'` string to each such string (space-or-tab for those leading spaces, but not newline so can't use `\s+`); then join them all with `'\n'`.  Altogether

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not @ARGV;

my $patt = 
    join '\n',  
    map { '[ \t]+' . join '\s+', map { quotemeta } split }
        'connect_supply_net VSS      -ports $port(VSSE)',
        'connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)',
        'connect_supply_net VDD_CPU  -ports $port(VDDPE)';

my $repl = <<'EOS';
    if { [llength $port(VSSE)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VSS -ports $port(VSSE)
    }
    if { [llength $port(VDDP)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
    }
    if { [llength $port(VDDPE)] > 0 } {
      connect_supply_net VDD_CPU -ports $port(VDDPE)
    }
EOS

local $^I = '.bak';  # edit "in-place" -- change the file. keep backup

local $/;            # read the file all at once

while (<>) {         # whole file read into $_
    s/$patt/$repl/g;
    print;
}
```

This is run by passing it the filename on the command-line. It should be far more robust to whitespace detail, even as it isn't as simple anymore.

The file is processed by setting the [in-place edit](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EI) (`$^I`) like `-i` command-lline option, and unsetting the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) (`$/`) so that the file is "slurped" all at once into a scalar.  Here we read it with the [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators). This is assigned to [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$ARG) by default, which the regex binds to by default.  The `print` goes to the file, by `$^I` (nothing is printed to screen).

Comment: I tried this with a bash script with export as you mentioned but it didn't work

Comment: @santy "_tried this with a bash script with export ... didn't work_"  -- oh? I tested and it works.  I don't know how you assign data to those bash variables? If you want to do it that way then every space matters, and linefeeds (line breaks) matter in particular.  Do you insist on using bash variables?  There are cleaner ways -- have this as a program and nicely define strings to work with, for example

Comment: I am assigning data to bash variables as you suggested but yes, the data is not in single line, there are line breaks and there is $ in it but I am putting everything in double quotes. I prefer bash variables as I think it would be just variable (old_string) to variable  (new_string) replacement.

Comment: @santy Then you have to be careful how to enter data. I copy-pasted the text into the prompt (`export v1="copy-here"`) and it worked but it can be tricky.  With a short program one can nicely enter that data in any way, it's much easier (or read data in from the command-line if preferred). I can post that if you wish, it's simple

Comment: yes, please post what you suggested. also what is short program ?

Comment: @santy   Added.  I decided that going with a "simple" copy-paste (of input) to match is far more fragile to various whitespace -- that's why it didn't work for you while it did for me (tabs?), so instead I build a regex for that input text.  It works in my tests and shouldn't be as sensitive to what exact whitespace is there.

Answer (score 2):

Sample files:

```
$ cat file.txt
some line
connect_supply_net VSS      -ports $port(VSSE)
another line
connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
yet another line
connect_supply_net VDD_CPU  -ports $port(VDDPE)
one more line
connect_supply_net ABCD  -ports $port(XYZ)
last line

$ cat replace.txt
connect_supply_net VSS      -ports $port(VSSE)
connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
connect_supply_net VDD_CPU  -ports $port(VDDPE)
```

**NOTE:** assumes entries in `replace.txt` are identical matches to lines in `file.txt` (to include the same amount of white space between fields), otherwise we'll need to add some more code

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR == NR     { replace[$0]; next }
$0 in replace { $3 = $3                          # squeeze multiple white spaces into single spaces throughout entire line
                $0 = "if { [llength " $4 "] > 0 } {" ORS "  " $0 ORS "}"
              }
1
' replace.txt file.txt
```

**NOTE:** if OP must use the `old_string` variable then replace `replace.txt` with `<(echo "${old_string}")`

This generates:

```
some line
if { [llength $port(VSSE)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VSS -ports $port(VSSE)
}
another line
if { [llength $port(VDDP)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
}
yet another line
if { [llength $port(VDDPE)] > 0 } {
  connect_supply_net VDD_CPU -ports $port(VDDPE)
}
one more line
connect_supply_net ABCD  -ports $port(XYZ)
last line
```

Comment: there is no replace.txt but only file.txt. I want to overwrite the file.txt after replacing those three lines

Comment: @santy - since you're manually creating the contents for `old_string` I assumed you were open to supplying the lines via any method that works (eg, a file); I've updated the answer to include a means of using `old_string` as the source

Comment: as for overwriting the `file.txt` with the modified lines, the easiest approach would be to direct the output to something like `tmp.txt` and afterwards run `mv tmp.txt file.txt`; if you're using `GNU awk` there is a way to have `awk` overwrite the source file but that'll require disabling/enabling the `inplace` module ... doable but not as 'clear' as using an intermediate file (eg, `tmp.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the lines in `$old_string`:

```bash
new_string=$(awk '{ printf "if { [llength %s] > 0 } {\n  %s\n}\n", $NF, $0 }' <<< $old_string)
```

The above works, but if we put the script in a separate file

```
# script.awk
{
    printf "if { [llength %s] > 0 } {\n", $NF
    print " " $0
    print "}"
}
```

Then the command will be cleaner:

```bash
new_string=$(awk -f script.awk <<< $old_string)
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this works. A example, probably with my use case would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v mystring="connect_supply_net" '
    $0 ~ mystring{
    printf "if { [llength %s] > 0 } {\n %s \n} \n", $NF, $0; next }
    {print}
' file
```

Comment: is there any generic solution such as passing a variable ? I have multiple multline strings that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @santy you can pass `mystring="connect_supply_net"`..

Comment: You aren't using any of the variables that `match()` populates so you don't need to call it, you could just do `$0 ~ mystring`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) we can fix all `connect_supply_net` commands to have the length guard, and put the `if` statements at the same indentation as the original statements.

We can also repair the bad indentation of the "Update states" block comment.

```
$ txr fix.txr data
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # supply connections
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if { [llength $port(VSSE)] > 0 } {
            connect_supply_net VSS -ports $port(VSSE)
        }
        if { [llength $port(VDDP)] > 0 } {
            connect_supply_net VDDS_CPU -ports $port(VDDP)
        }
        if { [llength $port(VDDPE)] > 0 } {
            connect_supply_net VDD_CPU -ports $port(VDDPE)
        }

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Update states
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@{indent}connect_supply_net @arg -ports $port(@port)
@    (output)
@{indent}if { [llength $port(@port)] > 0 } {
@{indent}    connect_supply_net @arg -ports $port(@port)
@{indent}}
@    (end)
@  (or)
#---@dashes
# Update states
#---@dashes
@    (output)
    #---@dashes
    # Update states
    #---@dashes
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Syntax coloed by Vim:

[image: Syntax colored by Vim]

Answer (score 0):

> using sed/awk/perl to replace multiline string

These by default work line-by-line, however they have features allowing you to work around that.

For demonstration purposed let `file.txt` content be

```
Able
Baker
Charlie
Dog
```

and desired output be

```
Able
Charlie
Baker
Dog
```

[GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) has `-z` option which does

> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the
> ASCII ‘NUL’ character) instead of a newline.

therefore if your file does not contain `\000` byte it will be treated as one line, thus command would be

```
sed -z 's|Baker\nCharlie|Charlie\nBaker|' file.txt
```

GNU `AWK` has `RS` (row-separator) and `ORS` (output row-sepatator) built-in variables, set them to pattern which never matches in your file and empty string to get all as one line behavior, e.g. `\000` byte (same as above `sed` example)

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\000";ORS=""}{sub(/Baker\nCharlie/,"Charlie\nBaker");print}' file.txt
```

`perl` sports slurp mode engaged by `-0777` and which could work together with `sed` mode engaged by `-p -e`, observe that syntax is same as in `sed` example

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's|Baker\nCharlie|Charlie\nBaker|' file.txt
```

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8, GNU Awk 5.1.0, perl 5, version 34, subversion 0)*